# How to change default onlongpress value on a phone?

Tags: android

My wife unintentionally gets to move around icons on her new Android phone. This is the first time she has a smart phone, and she is about to give up on it and demand back her old Nokia ;-) I've googled around and it appears that the onlongpress value is what should be adjusted. I have, however, found no way to do that. Can someone help with a suggestion or point me to an app that can change this value? In case there is no app that do this, I'd need a description of how to adjust the onlongpress default value (I have SDK installed). I'm surprised that I found nothing on this while googling (except for pinpointing the expression "onlongpress") but maybe I'm asking the wrong question? The phone is a Sony Ericsson E10i X10 and as far as I can see it runs a custom version of Android 1.6 (I don't have the phone here right now).

Answer (score 0):

You can't...
BUT you can download other launcher applications, like ADW Launcher, Launcher Pro, Go Launcher.
These launchers have an option to lock the desktop, which will prevent your wife from moving icons around.